# Why babel produce warnings about \rmfamily and \ttfamily with \babelfont

Tags: fonts, luatex, babel

I have babel v3.34 a simple example with beamer which I have added a sans serif font family with `\babelfont{sf}[Language=Default]{DejaVu Serif}`  produce such warnings

> Package babel Warning: The following fonts are not babel standard
>   families:
>
> - \rmfamily / lmr [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig; at 10.95pt
> - \ttfamily / lmtt [lmmono10-regular]: at 10.95pt
>     There is nothing intrinsically wrong with it, but 'babel' will no set Script and
>     Language. Consider defining a new family with \babelfont.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelfont{sf}[Language=Default]{Deja Vu Serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
Test 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Why I need to add a roman font family and a teletype font family?

( equivalent MWE with `fontspec` produce result without any warnings )

@JavierBezos

Comment: I'll rewrite the text to something like: “There is nothing intrinsically wrong with it, and if you do not need these fonts you can ignore this warning altogether. If they are used in the document, 'babel' will no set Script and Language for them, so you may consider defining a new family with \babelfont.”

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main purpose of `\babelfont` is to define at once in a multilingual document the fonts required by the different languages, with their corresponding language systems (script and language). So, if you load, say, 4 languages, `\babelfont{rm}{FreeSerif}` defines 4 fonts (with their variants, of course), which are switched with the language by `babel`. It's just a tool to make things easier and transparent to the user.

There is no real need to use `\babelfont` in a monolingual document, if you set the language system in `\setmainfont` (or not, depending on what you want).

`babel` assumes (actually, I assume :-)) that if you are using `\babelfont` for a family, very likely you want to define the rest of them. If you don't, you can find some inconsistencies between families. This checking is done at the beginning of the document, at a point where we cannot know which families will be used.

As the message explains, there is nothing intrinsically wrong with not defining all the families. In fact, there is nothing intrinsically wrong with not using `\babelfont` at all. But you must be aware that this may lead to some problems. And this is the very reason of the warning.

Answer (score 5):

The package `babel` is informing you that you lack definitions for the serif family and the mono family.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}[Language=Default]{DejaVu Serif}
\babelfont{sf}[Language=Default]{DejaVu Serif}
\babelfont{tt}[Language=Default]{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but my question is why babel requests \rmfamily and a \ttfamily font? I thought we just need a sans serif font with beamer. 
With  `fontspec` we add just the sans serif family.

Comment: @SalimBou Apparently you need to. It should be asked to Javier why.

Comment: Not at all. On the contrary, the warning makes clear “There is nothing intrinsically wrong with it”. I thought it was enough, but clearly it's not.

Comment: @JavierBezos Perhaps just an `Info` message, rather than a `Warning`?

Comment: @egreg But it warns about the fact Script and Language will not be set by babel automatically, which could lead to wrong results. So, it's not just an info, but a real warning.

Comment: Finally, I've created a new “type of warning”: it's printed to the console, because it's  relevant, but the message now reads “Info“ instead of “Warning”.