# lualatex / babel / fontspec: **Package babel Warning: The following fonts are not babel standard families** and other warnings

Tags: luatex, fontspec, texlive, babel, cjk

## Aim and Problem

- I want to generate an **English document** that **contains** some single (simplified) **Chinese characters**.
- I also want to use the famous `Noto` fonts (from Google), see https://www.google.com/get/noto/ and https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/.
- **Problem 1:** With my simple document below I get the following warnings which I want to get rid off and ideally understand.

**Warning 1**

User [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/) proposed `\babelfont{tt}{Latin Modern Mono}` for this warning.

> ```
> Package babel Warning: The following fonts are not babel standard families:
> (babel) * \ttfamily / lmtt
> (babel) [lmmono10-regular]:
> (babel) There is nothing intrinsically wrong with it, but
> (babel) 'babel' will no set Script and Language. Consider
> (babel) defining a new family with \babelfont.
> (babel) Reported on input line 2.
> ```

**Warning 2**

> ```
> Package fontspec Warning: Font "NotoSans" does not contain requested Script
> (fontspec) "Simplified".
> ```

**Warning 3**

> ```
> Package fontspec Warning: Language 'Chinese Simplified' not available for font
> (fontspec) 'NotoSans' with script 'CustomDefault'.
> ```

## (Potentially) Needed Steps to Reproduce the Problem

- I use **TeXlive** (up-to-date) on **Windows** and compile with **LuaLaTeX**..
- I downloaded the `notocjksc` fonts from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/notocjksc and put them in `C:\texlive\2019\texmf-dist\fonts\opentype\google`.
- I also downloaded `noto` fonts from https://www.ctan.org/pkg/noto and put them in the same path as `notocjksc`, see screenshot.
- **Problem 2:** It works but, I do not know which places (aka folders / paths) I can put fonts and if the folder name is relevant at all?! Can I also put it in `C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts` for example? (Is there a logic or manual that I have to follow?).
- I opened the **TeXlive Shell** and generated the `Font-Maps`, see screenshot.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Problem 3:** I do not understand why `\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{rm}{Noto Serif CJK SC}` works. When I open for example `NotoSerifCJKsc-Black.otf` then there is no `Noto Serif CJK SC` -- it is a `Noto Serif CJK SC Black` instead.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

% babel-package with option *english* as the document's default language
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% babelprovide for *english* (default language of the document)
\babelprovide[
    main,
    import,
    language = Default]
    {english}

% babelprovide for *chinese-simplified* (for some single words throughout the document)
\babelprovide[
    import,
    language = Chinese Simplified]
    {chinese-simplified}

%% Choose actual fonts for different font variants.
% Font for font variant "rm" (Serif)
\babelfont{rm}{Noto Serif}
% Font for font variant "sf" (Sans Serif --> Without Serif)
\babelfont{sf}{Noto Sans}
% Font for font variant "chinese-simplified"
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{rm}{Noto Serif CJK SC}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item English.
\item \foreignlanguage{chinese-simplified}{汉语。} (Chinese)
\end{itemize}   

\end{document}
```

### Related

- [Why babel produce warnings about \rmfamily and \ttfamily with \babelfont](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511079)
- [Mixing Chinese Characters with English (Main Language) in 2019 | What is the "State of the Art"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499910) (my own question)

> ### Remark
>
> - I am in China timezone, so I am a couple of hours in the future for
>     some of you. Keep that in mind when my replies may seem late :).
> - I used my fair share of LaTeX in the past years but when it comes to fonts I am really a bloody beginner :). So sorry of the questions
>     seems "stupid" or not well-enough researched.

Comment: Add `\babelfont{tt}{Latin Modern Mono}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks! I was still updating the question (three warnings). Using your hint removed one of them! There is also `NotoSansMono` as I see it -- but I can't use it instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Going to bed now (it's 23:09 local time), so I won't be able to reply shortly.

Comment: There is no need to load `english` twice. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513618/howto-multilanguage-babel#513667 . See also more relevant links in https://github.com/latex3/babel/wiki/Useful-links-to-tex.stackexchange , as well as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511079/why-babel-produce-warnings-about-rmfamily-and-ttfamily-with-babelfont/511296#511296 .

Comment: @JavierBezos Thanks for the hints. But I get even more warnings then :(. I am off to bed and can't try more deeply.

Comment: Warnings are not errors. They just warn about a potential problem. If everything is fine, then you can ignore them. As the warning about the fonts say, “There is nothing intrinsically wrong with this warning”. If you don't like the warning, you may turn off with the package option `silent`, or use the package `silence`.