# How can I typeset CJK strokes in LaTex file?

Tags: unicode, cjk, chinese

I am writing a thesis on Chinese handwriting. I need to typeset some special characters(㇀   ㇁   ㇂   ㇃   ㇄   ㇅   ㇆   ㇇   ㇈   ㇉   ㇊   ㇋   ㇌   ㇍   ㇎   ㇏ etc. )  (they are CJK strokes)

I want to use unicode in the text files to represent the strokes, i.e. \symbol{"31C0} should give me ㇀, because not all strokes can be rendered by my browser.

Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Answer (score 5):

With the latest versions of `babel` and `lualatex`, using a font from the Noto family:

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \babelprovide[onchar= ids fonts]{chinese}
 \babelfont[chinese]{rm}{NotoSerifCJKsc-Regular.otf}

 \begin{document}

 Chinese strokes: ㇀ ㇁ ㇂ ㇃ ㇄ ㇅ ㇆ ㇇ ㇈ ㇉ ㇊ ㇋ ㇌ ㇍ ㇎ ㇏.

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get this: Package babel Warning: The following fonts are not babel standard families: * \rmfamily = lmr "[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt * \sffamily = lmss "[lmsans10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;" at 10.0pt * \ttfamily = lmtt "[lmmono10-regular]:" at 10.0pt There is nothing intrinsically wrong with it, but 'babel' will no set Script and Language. Consider defining a new family with \babelfont. Reported on input line 2.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511079/why-babel-produce-warnings-about-rmfamily-and-ttfamily-with-babelfont#511296 . And the current manual, too. You may need to upgrade.

Answer (score 4):

You simply need a suitable font and then you can use lualatex or xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} %
\newfontfamily\chinesefont{Microsoft JhengHei UI}
\begin{document}

{\chinesefont ㇀ ㇁ ㇂ ㇃ ㇄ ㇅ ㇆ ㇇ ㇈ ㇉ ㇊ ㇋ ㇌ ㇍ ㇎ ㇏}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I wanna input unicode like 31C0 to represent ㇀, what should I do?

Comment: `\symbol{"31C0} \char"31C0 ^^^^31c0` will all work (and yes in the last variant the c is lowercase).

Comment: How do I install the font? I got error saying this font can't be found

Comment: It was part of my windows. I simply looked up which font my browser uses to show the glyphs of your question. Replace it with whatever font you have that contains the glyphs. The noto-font from Javier's answer should e.g. work.